# How to share a module as library on GitHub

Tags: android, github, android-studio, module

I create a module (as library) inside a project and I would like to share it on GitHub instead of creating jar and sending it always when I change this library.

**Is it possible to do in Android Studio?**

Comment: what exactly are you looking for ? There are many modules created with  Android Studio like this ( https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali ) already on github

Comment: I need just to selected that folder related to the library?

Comment: In Android Studio, I use the `VCS` -> `Import into Version Control` -> `Share project on github` option and select the file(s) to upload.

Comment: If you still want to share the jar from your GitHub project use JitPack.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure you have a .gitignore([1](https://gist.github.com/iainconnor/8605514)) file present in your source folder root. This is important or else Android Studio might import all files in your project
2. Then follow `VCS` -> `Import into Version Control` -> `Share project on github` and select files(s) to push to github as in below img.

[image]